# Bugzilla failed to fetch png and error 404/url not existing

Tags: apache2, bugzilla

Getting this error when running testserver.pl.

root@bugzilla:/var/www/webapps/bugzilla# ./testserver.pl http://localhost/bugzilla
TEST-OK Webserver is running under group id in $webservergroup.
**TEST-FAILED Fetch of images/padlock.png failed**
Your web server could not fetch http://localhost/bugzilla/images/padlock.png.
Check your web server configuration and try again.

Followed these guides:
https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/quick-start.html
https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/index.html (In-Depth setup)

I can access the apache webserver but not bugzilla. Kinda like Apache cant find Bugzilla.
Tried all available versions but still same error.
Cant find where its failing, setuped exactly like the guides, no difference anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Tried both quick start, in-depth and different versions of Bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Bugzilla installation instructions were so good that first blindly followed them without thinking much. After reading some Apache instructions, I found out that "Alias" should be used. So I used following site configuration that seems to be working:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla.conf :

```
Alias /bugzilla /var/www/webapps/bugzilla
<Directory /var/www/webapps/bugzilla>
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot but it didnt work for me :/ Did you follow the in-depth guide or quick start?